# BibTeX references on facing page

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm writing my thesis in LyX / LaTeX and using BibTeX to manage references. I prefer numerical references (eg. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKTKk.png)) instead of verbose references (eg. (Smith et al., 1993)) as I think it makes the text easier to read, but it bugs me that you have to constantly flick to the back to find the references. So, question:

**Is it be possible to print included references on the facing page?** I made a quick mockup to demonstrate: 
[image]

(bonus points if it's possible to have them at the same height as in the facing text, as shown)

I'm fairly new to LaTeX, so if this is impossible, that's an ok answer as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting them on another page could be difficult. But you could put them on the actual page in the margin and later cut this page in two and include it in another document e.g. with pdfpages. You will loose links but if the document is printed it shouldn't matter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[landscape,a3paper,left=21cm,marginparsep=1cm]{geometry}
\marginparwidth=\textwidth
\reversemarginpar
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
text text text \cite{bertram}\marginpar{\fullcite{bertram}} 
\lipsum[1]
blublbub\cite{doody}\marginpar{\fullcite{doody}}

\end{document}
```

But imho it is not a really sane idea. I doubt that your readers would like it if the text flow is constantly interrupted by "reference pages". If you want the references near by use \footcite to get them in the footnotes.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike - in my head it wouldn't interrupt text flow as this would purely be for the printed document, where these extra references are on what would otherwise be a blank page. I'll have a play with your suggestion and \footcite, which I've not seen before.

Comment: Also, I'm using LyX - do you know if there is any preamble I can use to somehow auto-generate the special citekeys you used above from what I've already entered?

Comment: I never haved used Lyx. I prefer to type commands instead of looking for the right button or menu entry.

Comment: Hah, yes. The more I fiddle with stuff the more I'm wondering if I should just switch to writing in LaTeX. Probably will do when I get closer to finishing, too much procrastination potential otherwise :) Thanks for the help - I basically have it working now from your code, looks great!